# My jupyter notebook doesn't recognize $\hdashline$, How do I fix it?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Per the [mathjax doc](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/tex.html) the symbol `\hdashline` is supported.

However, my jupyter notebook doesn't recognize it.

except this one

```
$\hdashline$
```

everything works well

[image]

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`$\hdashline$` can only be used in tables, so it won't be recognized.